# Converting dict's repeating key:value pair into parents

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a hypothetical list with repeating ids:

```
list = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'John', 'status': 'active'},
        {'id': '1', 'name': 'Doe', 'status': 'active'},
        {'id': '2', 'name': 'Jane', 'status': 'inactive'},
        {'id': '2', 'name': 'Appleseed', 'status': 'active'}]
```

I would like to turn this list into nested list/JSON, with group by id, with key label "member_info":

```
list_2 = [{'id': '1', 'member_info': [{'name': 'John', 'status': 'active'}
                                      {'name': 'Doe', 'status': 'active'}]},
          {'id': '2', 'member_info': [{'name': 'Jane', 'status': 'inactive'}
                                      {'name': 'Appleseed', 'status': 'active'}]}
```

I have tried using pandas group by, But it left out the id, and nothing got nested.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df = df.groupby('id')['name','status'].agg()
list_2 = df.to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby('id')[['name','status']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='row'))\
.reset_index(name='member_info').to_dict(orient='row')
```

---

```
[{'id': '1',
  'member_info': [{'name': 'John', 'status': 'active'},
   {'name': 'Doe', 'status': 'active'}]},
 {'id': '2',
  'member_info': [{'name': 'Jane', 'status': 'inactive'},
   {'name': 'Appleseed', 'status': 'active'}]}]
```

---

convert the data into this form 1st by using

`df.groupby('id')[['name','status']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='row')).reset_index(name='member_info')`

---

```
    id  member_info
0   1   [{'name': 'John', 'status': 'active'}, {'name'...
1   2   [{'name': 'Jane', 'status': 'inactive'}, {'nam...
```

Comment: That line break, mine eyes! Consider wrapping your one liner in parentheses so you can organize the functions like [this](https://pastebin.com/HaaaQzji). Looks cleaner and makes it easier to insert comments for each step. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I didn't know about that. It will make easier for me to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple operations like list comprehension. Here is an example:

```
dct = {}

# This yields a dictionory of {id_1: list_of_members, id_1: list_of_members} structure
for item in lst:
    if dct.get(item['id']): # existing id
        dct[item['id']].append({'name':item['name'], 'status':item['status']})
    else: # for new id
        dct[item['id']] = [{'name':item['name'], 'status':item['status']}] 

# List comprehension over compiled dictionary items.
ans = [{'id': k, 'member_info': v} for k,v in dct.items()]
```